# Setting up probability problem

Tags: probability

How can I calculate what is the probability of getting a red marble from one bowl, that was mixed with two bags of marble, first bag has `0.00052%` of red marbles in it, and the other bag has `0.000008%`. The bowl has `5%` marbles from the first bag, and `95%` from the other bag.
How can I calculate what is the probability of getting a red marble from that bowl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pick a marble. There is a 5% chance it came from the first bag and a 95% chance it came from the other.

So, the total probability of grabbing a red marble is:

$$0.05\times 0.0000052 + 0.95 \times 0.00000008$$